Remove multi-line pattern with sed
I have an AsciiDoc file and want to remove all collapsible blocks before rendering it as PDF using asciidoctor-pdf.
.Click to reveal the answer
[%collapsible]
====
This is the answer.
====

The text after the dot can be an arbitrary title.
I tried using sed '/\.(.* )\n\[\%collapsible\]/d;/====/,/====/d' to first delete the title and the [%collapsible] string and then delete the content between the ==== sections, but I cannot manage to get the line break to match.

please update the question with a larger set of sample data, eg, a couple lines of non-collapsible text, the collapsible block, then a couple more lines of non-collapsible text; also include the (wrong) output generated by your sed script and the (correct) expected output

at that link you provided there are a couple examples of collapsible blocks that do not show a leading line starting with a period; do all collapsible blocks have a leading line starting with a period? does that period always start in column #1? do you want to remove all collapsible blocks or just some collapsible blocks?

sed matches one line at a time, so there is no way a simple script could ever match anything with an embedded newline.
While you can write a sed script to, say, collect the previous line and the current line and then match against those, Awk is probably a better tool for nontrivial file processing.
awk 'BEGIN { RS=ORS="===="}
/(^|\n)\.[^\n]*\n\[%collapsible]/{
  sub(/(^|\n)\.[^\n]*\n\[%collapsible]/, ""); print; p=1; next }
!(p && p--)' file

The BEGIN section sets the record separator and output record separator to "====". With this setting, Awk will process the lines between these demarcators as one record (or "line") and so the rest of the processing becomes rather easy.
In very brief, if the current record contains a match on the regex, we replace that part with nothing, and set p to 1. We print the remainder, then skip to the next record.
For the next record, p will be 1, so we skip that, but we also decrement p so that it will be 0 again for the next record after that.
This will probably not work correctly if the [%collapsible] text is not immediately before a separator. If you need to control that behavior in more detail, probably post more detailed requirements.
Demo: https://ideone.com/0FwN64
This simple demo also adds a ==== at the end, which you might not want. Again, more sophisticated behavior is possible but probably needs more sophisticated requirements.  But here is a quick and dirty hack to avoid that.
awk 'BEGIN { RS="===="; ORS = ors = "" }
/(^|\n)\.[^\n]*\n\[%collapsible]/{
  sub(/(^|\n)\.[^\n]*\n\[%collapsible]/, ""); print ors $0; ors=RS; p=1; next }
!(p && p--) { print ors $0; ors=RS }' file

Demo: https://ideone.com/DFTDG6

This almost works like what I was looking for. [%collapsible] is always immediately before the separator, but I would want to remove the ==== at the end too.

With GNU sed you can change the line orientation with the option -z.
In a happy flow, you won't have =-characters between the two === markers.
The happy flow solution is
sed -rz 's/\.[^\n]*\n\[%collapsible]\n====\n[^=]*\n====\n//g' inputfile

When you know an unique character that is not in your input, you can improve the solution. In Unix/Linux files, the character \r can be used.
sed 's/^===$/\r/' inputfile |
  sed -rz 's/\.[^\n]*\n\[%collapsible]\n\r\n[^\r]*\n\r\n//g' |
  sed 's/\r/===/'

